# Is it possible to set cell background color to some degree of opacity?

Tags: html

I am using FrontPage2000. (I do not use CSS) On my page I have a table; 4x4 cells, table background is a photo.  I want to write text inside one cell; so to see it I set this:  bgcolor="#FF00FF">
But what I really want is some degree of opacity - I'd like to set it to 50-75% white/opaque so I can write text in this cell using a black font; but still see some blur of the photo underlying. (Or I could set it to "dark" and use a white font?) So I guess my question boils down to this - what is the magic setting of bgcolor=opaque? I tried to find this out  here:https://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm but was not successful. Please let me know steve at freisco com

Comment: You need to know that `bgcolor` has been marked in the standard as obsolete. Oh, I just went to your site. You need to know that almost everything on your site is obsolete!

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you're not exactly up to date with the Tool, you use, but anyway.
At the end, this is going to be shown in a web browser, right? And they support transparency. So, all you need to do is setting a bgcolor with 4 'colors' where the last 2 hex numbers is the transparency, like: `#FF00FF7F`. This should Work in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

FrontPage2000 supports CSS so you could easily use inline CSS to accomplish this task. Where you would put bgcolor="" just put the following instead:

```
style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);"
```

Where rbga means Red Blue Green Alpha, 255, 255, 255 is white, and 0.75 is 75% opacity.

Comment: Chils, thanks again for you idea.  Note 5th line from bottom where I've keyed in exactly what you suggest.  It does not work.

Comment: HOLD THE PRESSES!  Evidently this does not work in "Normal" view within FP2K itself, BUT when shipped to the internet, I get some opacity!!!

Comment: So see my very rough start, have a look here:  http://www.freisco.com/cell_backgrounds.htm

Comment: Now, I am almost ashamed to ask for more help........  But here goes. If you go to this page above, you will note in the right side that the photo is beginning to repeat itself again.  Is there a way I can make this image appear once; in full screen, set as a fixed element; whereas the table information would scroll? (full screen=1 full photo; no more no less) ie - suppose the table had 3 columns but 30 rows; with 10 rows you won't see unless you start scrolling down. I'd like the background to remain fixed, but the table to scroll.  Even if no help is offered, I am VERY THANKFUL for opacity.

Comment: Glad I could help! Since there's a lot of things you want done on your website and you seem to be enthusiastic about learning, I suggest you take an introductory course on CSS. Knowing how to put all the pieces together yourself will help you immensely with this project and future ones. There are lots of free resources online. I also recommend that you update your IDE. FrontPage2000 is outdated and has been replaced with Microsoft Expressions (which is very good and is free).

Comment: @SteveFreeman To answer your question, though, just add style="overflow: auto;" to the container that you want to be scrollable and style="background-size: cover;" to the container you want the background image to stop repeating.